# Using negative number in PHP DateTime::modify()

Tags: php, datetime

This code:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime;
$dateTime->modify('+ -60 seconds');
```

works in 5.2.6 but not in 5.3.

I have already identified a few solutions but I just want to know how those who also encountered it solved the problem.

I am hoping there is some setting to allow the above format in newer versions so that code changes can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I think Datetime::sub() works for you for negative values in PHP 5.3.
Check this reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm on php 5.3.9 and I find that

$date->modify('+ -60 seconds');

throws a parse warning
but these work:

$date->modify('-60 seconds');
$date->modify('+-60 seconds');

Both these work:
$date->modify('-2 days');
$date->modify('-2 day');

but of course one still has to watch out for the months not doing what a human might call 'add  or subtract a month', even with the add and sub functions.

see eg 3. http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php